# Tensor-hom adjunction in a general closed monoidal category

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let $(C,\otimes,1)$ be a closed (not necessarily symmetric) monoidal category with all finite limits and colimits and with the internal hom functor $[b,-]$ right adjoint to $(-)\otimes b$, for any $b\in C$. Let $r$ and $s$ be monoids in $C$ and $x$ be an $(r,s)$-bimodule. Does one always have an adjunction
$$
(-)\otimes_r x\colon RMod_r\rightleftarrows RMod_s\colon [x,-]_s,
$$
where $(-)\otimes_r x$ is the coequalizer of $(-)\otimes r\otimes x \rightrightarrows (-)\otimes x$ and $[x,-]_s$ is the equalizer of $[x,-]\rightrightarrows [x\otimes s,-]$ (the arrows being naturally defined)?

Comment: I think I got it. One should in addition require that $Hom_C(−,)$ converts colimits to limits and $Hom_(,−)$ preserves limits. Then one should use the Fubini theorem for limits in sets. Maybe though this statement already appeared in any book or paper?